# Formatting a String to be Converted to Double

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert a `string` to `double`. The incoming string is always going to be a whole number...no decimals. So, for example "90".

```
double percentToCheck = Convert.ToDouble(String.Format("{0:0.00}", SomeEntity.KeyIDs.SomePercentTrigger));
```

`SomePercentTrigger` is the % that I will be converting.

I get a "string is not in the correct format" error so how should I format this string? I've got to format it because if I don't I get the same error with just this during the conversion:

```
double percentToCheck = Convert.ToDouble(SomeEntity.KeyIDs.SomePercentTrigger);
```

UPDATED:

`SomePercentTrigger` is simply a `string` such as "80"..it'll always be a whole number too.

Comment: What does `SomePercentTrigger` actually look like?

Comment: do you have any example of your input data?

Comment: Do, you tried Double.Parse() for achieving this.

Comment: @kalyan `Convert.ToDouble()` actually *uses* `double.Parse()`.

Comment: Not to be a doubter, but if `SomePercentTrigger` was actually just the string "80", you wouldn't be getting this error. Can you inspect it in the debugger, or print it out? What is its type?

Comment: there is no %, definitely not and no chance of that happening either for this one.

Comment: @link664 deleted my less code reason...fyi

Comment: @link664 `Convert.ToDouble()` will return 0.0 for `null`, whereas `double.Parse()` will throw an exception. If you don't want to worry about null checking, `Convert.ToDouble()` requires less code.

Comment: @dlev - noted, thanks for the knowledge.  Hence why most of the time I use double.TryParse()

Comment: @CoffeeAddict if that string really were "80", this would mean that you are the first one to discover a major bug in one of the most frequently used functions of the framework. That seems reasonably imlausible to me

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**
Your string is `"52.0"`.

It must be the `'.'` that causes the `FormatException`.
You are probably on a machine where `'.'` is *not* set as the decimal point (e.g. I live in Germany and use German regional settings. Our decimal point is `','` )

To get around this problem you need to parse the string using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

```
var value = double.Parse(myString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`InvariantCulture` should be used for the parts of your application that revolve around data storage. Make sure you use it as well when converting doubles to strings `Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));`

---

I suspect that `SomeEntity.KeyIDs.SomePercentTrigger` has some invalid characters in it (something other than digits, '.' and a optional leading '-'), say for example "80%"

So you're getting a `FormatException` on this line

```
double percentToCheck = Convert.ToDouble(String.Format("{0:0.00}", SomeEntity.KeyIDs.SomePercentTrigger));
```

because `{0:0.00}` formatting rules are only valid for numeric values.

Also you get the very same exception here:

```
double percentToCheck = Convert.ToDouble(SomeEntity.KeyIDs.SomePercentTrigger);
```

because "80%" can not be converted into a double.

You should either

- put some logging right in front of the failing statement
- or debug that code

and see what the **actual** content of `SomeEntity.KeyIDs.SomePercentTrigger` is.

Comment: Agreed, if the string formatting and parsing aren't working the obvious reason is that the data is wrong.

Comment: the incoming data for an example is "52.0"

Comment: @CoffeeAddict You need to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to get the '.' right: double.Parse(SomeEntity.KeyIDs.SomePercentTrigger, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Answer (score 2):

Use `double.Parse(string)` or alternatively `double.TryParse(string, out value)`

Comment: `Convert.ToDouble()` actually uses `double.Parse()`. If the former fails, the latter will as well.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense to try to format a string. You would have to parse it to a number first in order to format it. Anyhow, there is no problem in parsing a number without decimals as a double, so the string is probably not containing what you think it does.

If the string contains a number in integer format, parse the string as an integer, and then convert the integer to a double:

```
double percentToCheck = (double)Int32.Parse(SomeEntity.KeyIDs.SomePercentTrigger);
```

Comment: still get the error using that.  The value for SomePercentTrigger is 52.0 and here's my code which still throws me the string format error:  double percentToCheck = (double)Int32.Parse( SomeEntity.KeyIDs.SomePercentTrigger);

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: if `SomePercentTrigger` contains the string `"52.0"` then it's not a number without decimals. It's formatted as a floating point number, so you have to parse it like that: `double percentToCheck = double.Parse(SomeEntity.KeyIDs.SomePercentTrigger, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: It's not even taking the invariant cluture....I get a "CultureInfo" does not exist in the current context

Comment: @CoffeAddict: The `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is so that it always uses period as decimal separator regardless of the local culture settings. You need `using System.Globalization;` at the top, or specify `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in the code.